# Google Play - UPLOAD NEW APK failed - different certificate with fingerprint

Tags: android, intellij-idea, gradle, apk, release

I'm having issues generating a new apk that I want to upload to Google Play store.

Recently I have opted to use gradle to directly sign the release apk. For this I'm reading an properties file which has all the details regarding the keystore which was used to sign the apk.
Previously I was using the wizard from IntelliJ to generade the release apk.

It seems that the wizard signs the apk differently than gradle thus I'm unable to upload the new apk to Google Play.

PS: The generated apk by gradle is in [root project][root module]\build\outputs\apk\

Does anyone know if I'm doing something wrong or is gradle using other methods to sign the apk thus making it different than the one signed through the wizard.

Comment: You might find something useful at the existing questions on determining signer, verifying certificates, etc.

Comment: Running "jarsigner -verify -verbose -certs my.apk" command showed me that apk signin process from gradle was messed up. It was always taking only the latest keystore file.
I'll post my updated build.gradle file which works with different keystores for each flavor.

Answer (score 1):

My problem seemed to be with how I implemented build.gradle. I fixed it and this is how it should look like when you want to have different keystore for each flavor:

```
signingConfigs {
    println 'Sign apk config'

    falvor1 {
        /** Details for signing the application */
        def props = new Properties()
        props.load(new FileInputStream(rootProject.file("release.properties.flavor1")))

        storeFile file(rootProject.file(props.keyStore))
        storePassword props.keyStorePassword
        keyAlias props.keyAlias
        keyPassword props.keyAliasPassword
    }

    flavor2 {
        /** Details for signing the application */
        def props = new Properties()
        props.load(new FileInputStream(rootProject.file("release.properties.flavor2")))

        storeFile file(rootProject.file(props.keyStore))
        storePassword props.keyStorePassword
        keyAlias props.keyAlias
        keyPassword props.keyAliasPassword
    }
}

/** Add product flavours for all variants of application */
productFlavors {

    flavor1 {
        // Update the application ID/ Package name
        applicationId "com.my.application.flavor1"
        /* Update the version code & version name */
        versionCode 100
        versionName "1.0.0.1"
    }

    flavor2 {
        // Update the application ID/ Package name
        applicationId "com.my.application.flavor2"
        /* Update the version code & version name */
        versionCode 200
        versionName "2.0.0.2"
    }
}

buildTypes {
    debug {

        runProguard false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'

        zipAlign true

    }


    release {

        //Only use the release key on a release buildType
        productFlavors.flavor1.signingConfig signingConfigs.flavor1
        productFlavors.flavor2.signingConfig signingConfigs.flavor2

        runProguard true
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'

        zipAlign true


    }
}
```

*release.properties.flavor* structure

```
// Name of the keystore file
keyStore=flavor1.keystore
// keystore password
keyStorePassword=flavor1pass
// Key alias
keyAlias=flavor1_alias
// Key password
keyAliasPassword=flavor1pass
```